# Shimano 600 downtube shifter installation

Tags: installation

I recently purchased some vintage 6-speed Shimano 600 downtube shifters. The package came with all the parts in a ziploc bag and it looks a bit bewildering. Any idea where I can find an installation diagram for this assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally these levers came with three parts per side - the concave bit that goes on the downtube, the lever and the screw to hold it all together. The concave bit only goes on one way - turn them 180 degrees if it is not screwing together. And that should be it, see:

http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Dura-Ace/SL-BS78/SI-6J60A_En_v1_m56577569830605258.pdf

But you have them in pieces. You need these instructions:

The way they are set up is:

1. Chrome concave plastic piece goes on first, concave side toward frame, Flat side faces out
2. Brass washer
3. Thin steal washer, 2 little protrusions toward frame, Make sure not to bracket the 2 little protrusions between the little metal tab on frame. Things won't fit or shift if you do this. The tab on the frame is a stop for the lever.
4. Shift lever, Make sure the tab on the inside of the lever goes in the notch between the 2 little protrusions
5. Relatively thick rubber\metal washer. Metal side faces frame
6. screw

http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-162825.html

Answer (score 1):

The [Shimano Techdocs](http://techdocs.shimano.com/) site has installation manuals and exploded diagrams of Shimano components. While it's possible your shifters may not be on the site, you can probably find a set that's similar enough.